# Calculating responsive % for 960 grid padding

Tags: css, responsive-design, percentage, 960.gs, calculated-columns

I'm building my first responsive website based on the 960 grid and I've run into something that I can't quite work out.

Getting right to the point I have 2 columns in my grid:

.left: 720px total width
.right: 240px total width

Both of these include 10px of padding on both the left and right so in my fixed layout I would be applying the following which fit perfectly:

```
.left {
    width: 700px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    float: left;
}
.right {
    width: 220px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    float: right;
}
```

All well and good, but now I'm using the **target / context = result** formula to calculate this grid so it's responsive.  I have a containing div which is 90% and here are my calculations:

```
.left {
    width: 72.916667%;
    padding: 0 1.388889%;
    float: left;
}
.right {
    width: 22.916667%;
    padding: 4.166667%;
    float: right;
}
```

I believe those calculations to be correct, but my right hand column is always dropping down to the next line because it doesn't fit.

Any help where I'm going wrong would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your padding calculations are incorrect: `10px / 960px = 1.0416667%`

Basically, you need to divide by the *total span*, e.g. the width that (originally) corresponds to 100%. In your case, that's `960px`.

Comment: Thanks Mattias.  I had already figured this out but I accepted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to reduce your calculations a little, I'm getting 101.38889 when I add those values up ;)

Comment: It's even higher. The padding is specified for *both* left and right side, so you have to count them twice.

Comment: +1 for pointing out it didn't add up to 100.  This is what forced me to try something different.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out through trial and error.

Turns out that I was calculating the padding incorrectly using the columns width as the context rather than the containing div.

An amended calculation saw 10 / 960 = 1.041667 for all the padding and it now fits.

Comment: Damn, ninja'd. Good thing you figured it out yourself though. :)